# fe_sendauth: error sending password authentication

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, database-connection, postgis, django-settings

I'm now learning Django and am following the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/) step by step.

When I proceeded to chapter 5 to connect my Django project to my database, I can't get it to connect. I get the error:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Here's the code:

`settings.py` configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'postgis',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXX',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '8904',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
}
```

But when I'm testing the connection and settings in Python shell with these codes:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor=connection.cursor()
```

the shell replies with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-    py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\
postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 177, in _cursor
self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

then I reinstalled the PostgreSQL and pycopg2 packages. I started pgAdminIII to run the server and connected to database, then I run the same code in python shell, but the problem still exists.

Need Help!

Comment: The error in the title and the one in the traceback don't match. Which one was it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a guess, you're using the wrong password, or your `pg_hba.conf` isn't correctly configured.

Can you connect using `psql` with the desired credentials? Try:

```
psql -U postgres -W -p 8904 postgis
```

If not, check `pg_hba.conf` to see the `postgres` user is using `ident` or `md5` security. If you want to use password connections it needs to be `md5`. If you change the setting, use `pg_ctl reload` or just restart PostgreSQL to make the change take effect.

You can find `pg_hba.conf` by connecting to your DB with `psql` and running `SHOW hba_file;`. Eg:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW hba_file;'
```

Note that **you should never user a PostgreSQL superuser for an application connection** anyway.  Create a new user and have Django use that user on a new database. For example, to create a user named `django` and a database named `django_db` that's owned by the `django` user:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -SDR -P django
sudo -u postgres createdb -O django_db django;
```

The `-SDR` makes the default explicit, that the `django` user should not be a superuser and should not have `CREATEDB` or `CREATEUSER` rights.

Comment: Thanks Craig! I followed your words, and it did work. Do I have to edit hba_file for different databases?

Comment: @IanZhao I don't understand what you mean by that question.

Answer (score 5):

With PostgreSQL 14+ there's a new way to get the `fe_sendauth: error sending password authentication` error.

As documented in the [PostgreSQL 14 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html), both the client and server now use the OpenSSL EVP API, which enforces FIPS mode. If your passwords use `md5`, you will be unable to login using PostgreSQL 14 if  your FIPS configuration disallows `md5`.

You can check your default `password_encryption` setting using `SHOW password_encryption;`, and update a single user manually with:

```sql
SET password_encryption  = 'scram-sha-256'; 
ALTER USER "user" with password 'password';
```

To permanently change the default `password_encryption` setting for new users' passwords, update `postgresql.conf`:

```
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

From the PostgreSQL 14 release notes:

> - Change SHA1, SHA2, and MD5 hash computations to use the OpenSSL EVP API (Michael Paquier)
>
>   This is more modern and supports FIPS mode.
> - Change the default of the password_encryption server parameter to `scram-sha-256` (Peter Eisentraut)
>
>   Previously it was `md5`. All new passwords will be stored as SHA256 unless this server setting is changed or the password is specified in MD5 format. Also, the legacy (and undocumented) Boolean-like values which were previously synonyms for `md5` are no longer accepted.

Comment: Wow, this is confusing. For some reason I was able to connect fine using psql, but I couldn't when I used psycopg2 with the same settings.  This fixed my issue (using PostgreSQL 12).

Comment: This happens with a Postgres 14 client too, not just the server version. Maybe your psychopg2 is using a newer libpq library than psql? Glad the fix worked though.